# The Twilight Zone episode: a family unknowingly time travels

Tags: episode-identification, the-twilight-zone

For a poll I've been conducting about people's favorite *The Twilight Zone* episodes, one friend wrote back to me:

> Unfortunately I have to admit that I don’t remember too many Twilight Zone episodes but there is one that I will never forget. Don’t know the name of the episode but there was a family that time traveled a few minutes (unbeknownst to them) and the scenes were all white and they could see men painting the real time behind them.

Which episode is this?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like ["A Matter of Minutes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes).

> The Wrights, a young married couple, wake up one day to the sounds of construction. When they investigate they find time has stopped. Meanwhile, a crew of blue-clad construction workers are busy removing the furniture in their house and replacing it with new.

While not everything matches up, the rest of the episode described on the Wikipedia link does include "running into a white void" and discovering they are a few hours (rather than minutes) out of sync with normal time.

Comment: http://twilightzone.wikia.com/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes

Comment: @WilliamKozy: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia entry linked in this answer, that episode was based on Theodore Sturgeon's 1948 short story, ["Yesterday was Monday"](http://www.unz.com/print/Unknown-1948q1-00054).